# Packaging a Groovy application

Tags: groovy, compilation

I want to package a Groovy CLI application in a form that's easy to distribute, similar to what Java does with JARs. I haven't been able to find anything that seems to be able to do this. I've found a couple of things like [this](http://www.jroller.com/berni/entry/wrapping_groovy_scripts_as_executable) that are intended for one-off scripts, but nothing that can compile an entire Groovy application made up of a lot of separate Groovy files and resource data.

I don't necessarily need to have the Groovy standalone executable be a part of it (though that would be nice), and this is not a library intended to be used by other JVM languages. All I want is a simply packaged version of my application.

**EDIT**:
Based on the couple of responses I got, I don't think I was being clear enough on my goal. What I'm looking for is basically a archive format that Groovy can support. The goal here is to make this easier to distribute. Right now, the best way is to ZIP it up, have the user unzip it, and then modify a batch/shell file to start it. I was hoping to find a way to make this more like an executable JAR file, where the user just has to run a single file.

I know that Groovy compiles down to JVM-compatible byte-code, but I'm not trying to get this to run as Java code. I'm doing some dynamic addition of Groovy classes at runtime based on the user's configuration and Java won't be able to handle that. As I said in the original post, having the Groovy executable is included in the archive is kind of a nice-to-have. However, I do actually need *Groovy* to be executable that runs, not Java.

Comment: Why not just create a jar of your application and distribute that along with the required Groovy jars (and jars you depend on) like you would with Java?

Answer (score 4):

The Gradle Cookbook shows how to make a "fat jar" from a groovy project: http://wiki.gradle.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-Creatingafatjar

This bundles up all the dependencies, including groovy.  The resulting jar file can be run on the command line like:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Comment: Check out my comment to Brian's answer. This would work if I needed a Java-compatible JAR, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of success using a combination of the [eclipse Fat Jar plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) and [Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/).

Essentially this becomes a 'Java' problem not a groovy problem.  Fat Jar is painless to use.  It might take you a couple of tries to get your single jar right, but once all the dependencies are flattened into a single jar you are now off an running it at the command line with

```
java -jar application.jar
```

I then wrap these jars as a service.  I often develop standalone groovy based services that perform some task.  I set it up as a service on Windows server using Yet Another Java Service and schedule it using various techniques to interact with Windows services.

Comment: This seems to get close to what I'm looking for, but I've got a couple of kind of advanced things going on in the application. You can configure it to use Groovy classes defined at runtime by the user, so I'm fairly confident that Groovy still needs to be the executable running my app, not Java.

Comment: I'm using methods introduced by Groovy on String in this deployment, so I don't see it as any different then meta programming on your own classes.  Compare the JDK docs for String:

Java - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/
Groovy - http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#findAll(java.util.regex.Pattern)

Comment: The Groovy classes are defined in plaintext Groovy scripts and provided at runtime. Anything you have in your Groovy code, including metaclass stuff, at compile time can compile to JVM bytecode, but this is different. Users would have to compile their scripts into .class files in order to use them with Java. With Groovy, you can just add the plaintext scripts to classpath, which is awesome and I'd like to preserve that behavior.